# AWS - How can i create an EMR cluster using spot block

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

AWS has recently introduced spot block where I can block the spot instances for maximum of 6 hours. I want to create an emr cluster with these blocked instances. is it possible?

If possible, can you please give me pointers on the same. 
I searched on internet and contacted aws forums with no success.